# Difficulties finding solutions for a valid url from a javascript ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

When using MVC5 and WebApi 2, I'm having difficulties finding solutions for a valid url from a javascript ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
      async : true,
      type : 'GET',
      url : '../api/Skills/UpdateSkill/' + skillPk + '/' + userPk + '/' +  date,
      contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success : function(response) {

      },
      error: function(xhr) {
          alert("Oops! It appears there has been an error. Please try     again.\n\nError Thrown: " + xhr.responseText);
      }
});
```

My WebApi looks like this

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult ScheduleSkill(Guid skillPk, Guid userPk, DateTime date)
```

When the call comes from a page for example http://localhost:8080/Action/View .
The '../api/Skills/UpdateSkill ' url works.
However if your MVC view contains paraemeters such as http://localhost:8080/Action/View/Edit/1 . Then the url does not work because it is sent as

```
'Action/View/Edit/api/Skills/Updateskill' .
```

My question is regarding forming the url in the ajax call.
If my view has 3 parameters is there a better way than stating

```
'../../../api/skills/updateskill'
```

in the ajax call, so that the call is sent to the appropriate directory?

This can be especially annoying if there are 6 parameters or an unknown amount of parameters. How can you form the url in an ajax call?

Comment: You put the absolute path URL.

Comment: How about a `<base>` tag?

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Those will work.

Answer (score -1):

Try putting your data into a 'data' property like this.

```
        var skillPk = "skillPk";
        var userPk = "userPk";
        var ApplicationRoot = window.location.origin;

        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: 'GET',
            url: ApplicationRoot + '/api/Skills/Updateskill',
            data: { skillPk: 'skillPkValue', userPk: 'userPkValue' },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert("Oops! It appears there has been an error. Please try     again.\n\nError Thrown: " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
```

I created a sample solution in MVC5 and WebAPI 2. 
https://github.com/duyn9uyen/SampleWebApi2

When you run the app, enter the url: http://localhost:[portNumber]/Home/Skill/3

You will be presented with a view that just outputs the parameter you have provided. In this case, "3." Now you are on a view who's URL contain's a parameter. On the pageload of that view, an ajax call will be made to `'api/SkillsController/Updateskill'`

You will see the two parameters populated. (I changed `skillPk` and `userPk` to be strings and I dropped the date parameter because I wanted to make it simple.) You can put a breakpoint on `SkillsController/Updateskill` to see the values get passed in via querystring (a HttpGet). You will see the page throw a javascript alert with '200' if everything goes well.

Comment: A mark down with no explanation? I'll be a good sport. I've updated my answer and provided a sample solution.